# Overwrite property during maven release fails

Tags: maven, properties, release, maven-release-plugin

I've added a new property named  in the properties section.
I'm using this property in one on my plugins:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <id>...</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>read-dev</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <files>
                <file>${dev-file}</file>
            </files>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <phase>pre-clean</phase>
        <id>...</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>read-dev</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <files>
                <file>${dev-file}</file>
            </files>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

I need to overwrite this property.

It works perfect when I run: mvn clean deploy -Ddev-file=tmp.dev

But it fails to read the new dev file when I run:
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Ddev-file=tmp.dev

Do you have any idea of what might cause this bug?
or what else should I check?

Comment: The `validate` phase is part of the _Default Lifecycle_, the `pre-clean` phase is part of the _Clean Lifecycle_, see [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). You don't perform either of them but you invoke goals of the [`release` plugin.](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/). Though one of them has the same name as one of the phases,  `clean`, a _phase_ is something completely different than a `goal`. Hence, the steps of your POM are not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Passing arguments to the release plugin is a beauty:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Darguments=-Ddev-file=tmp.dev
```